# How to mirror multiple iPhone via USB (no wifi)

Tags: macos, iphone, mirroring

Is there a way to mirror multiple devices via lightning cable ?

I can do it for one of them with Quicktime, but when I launch multiple instance of Quicktime App, this don't let me use a second video recording..

I need to mirror 3 iPhone.

I can't use wireless mirroring for technical issues.

Comment: mirroring as in showing  iphone screen on Bigger  screen correct?

Comment: yes ! Show multiple iPhone screen on my Macbook. For a demo presentation with a projector.